# How to determine symmetry of the system from the term symbol?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, term-symbols

I'm studying term symbols. I can derive them mechanically from the electron configuration using the complete table of microstates.

Let's consider a typical example - an atomic carbon with the electron configuration $1s^22s^22p^2$.

It has states ${}^3P_0, {}^3P_1, {}^3P_2, {}^1D_2, {}^1S_0$.

But now, how can I derive the symmetries for each of these states? I need to compute their energies in some specialized software (Molpro), but I don't see the exact connection between the atomic term symbol and its symmetry.

---

#### Question

Let's work with the $D_{2h}$ point group.

1. The ${}^1S_0$ state is supposed to be totally symmetric, i.e. to have $A_g$ irreducible representation.

   **But how can I determine it without previously knowing?**

   I know, thank to [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/105065/53653), that ${}^1S_0$ wavefunction should be a linear combination of 3 microstates:

   \begin{align}
   |L = 0, M_L = 0\rangle & = \frac{1}{\sqrt 3} \left( |m_{l1}= 1, m_{l2} = -1\rangle 
   \right. \\ & \qquad \qquad \left. 
   + |m_{l1}= -1, m_{l2} = 1\rangle 
   \right. \\ & \qquad \qquad \left. 
   - |m_{l1}= 0, m_{l2} = 0\rangle \right)
   \end{align}

   But I see no way to use it to determine the ${}^1S_0$ symmetry in $D_{2h}$ or any other point group...
2. The second example are ${}^3P_0, {}^3P_1, {}^3P_2$ states - they're supposed to have $B_{1g}, B_{2g}, B_{3g}$ irreducible representations. But again - **how can I derive them just from the electron configuration and the term symbol?**

   I understand basics of molecular symmetry and I can draw the molecular orbital diagrams for ground states. My confusion lies mostly in the situation, where I can theoretically describe the electron configuration using direct product of irreducible representation of single orbitals (like it's described in [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/87554/53653)), but I don't know what to do, when the state (described by an atomic term symbol) is a linear combination of multiple such configurations (microstates).

I'd be very grateful for an explanation using basic terms and maybe a derivation step-by-step example or pictures, as I'm a real beginner and the topic seems to be quite confusing so far.